# Magento2 API update multiple inventory items

Tags: magento2, api, soap, rest-api, inventory

I'm developing integration with magento. My client want to update his inventory via REST or API, the problem is that he has thousands of products and it will take a lot of time to update them one by one. I didn't found the way to update many inventory items neither from SOAP nor from REST. (For previous versions i used catalogInventoryStockItemMultiUpdate)

How to update a lot of inventory items in 1 call?

Answer (score 1):

There is no Multiupdate. You would need to create such a Module. However a faster option to update only the stock is this: `[PUT] /V1/products/{productSku}/stockItems/{itemId}`

If you will develop such a Module, you should also make your code to do something similar to the code behind that call.